# Using Nodemailer with Hotmail/Node.js

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I know there are a lot of posts about this and i've cycled through a good amount of them, none of them panning out.  So here we go:

Trying to send an email via Nodemailer in NestJS application.  Tested with the documentations's pre done eretheral test email and it worked fine.  Now i'm trying to connect it to the hotmail account (which I have attained an app password) and no luck so far. Here's the function:

```
export async function sendEmail(createTicketDto: CreateTicketDto) {
  const { username, email, ticket_body, issue_type } = createTicketDto;
  const emailBody = `
  User ${email} reporting issue regarding ${issue_type}:\n
\t${ticket_body}\n
  \t\tActive username is: ${username}`;

  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'hotmail',
    host: 'smtp-mail.outlook.com',
    secure: false,
    port: 587,
    auth: {
      user: 'xxx@hotmail.com',
      pass: 'PASSWORD',
    },
    tls: {
      ciphers: 'SSLv3',
    },
  });
  console.log(emailBody);
  const mailData = await transporter.sendMail({
    from: '"XXXSUPPORT"<XXX@hotmail.com>',
    to: 'YYY@gmail.com',
    subject: issue_type,
    text: emailBody,
  });
  Logger.log(`Email sent with ID:  ${mailData.messageId}`);
  return mailData;
}
```

The error being returned resembles:

```
[Nest] 22727  - 02/10/2023, 1:32:32 PM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Invalid login: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [MN2PR17CA0007.namprd17.prod.outlook.com 2023-02-10T18:32:32.130Z 08DB0B4DDC8F1521]
```

Feedback is appreciated, thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So problem has been resolved, however a few notes for myself (and anyone who stumbles across this):

```
  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'hotmail',
    auth: {
      user: process.env.EMAIL_USER,
      pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASS,
    },
  });
```

After that it was still failing, so based on a throwaway line in another forum post, I sent a test email to and from the hotmail account, and... it worked!  So apparently, if you haven't sent any emails from the target send account, at least in the case of hotmail, it will not work.

Comment: i am in this issue now but it hasn't worked, please using microsoft365 , please can you give me the details to use here:  # Mail server configuration
MAIL_SERVER=????????
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=xxxxxxxx
MAIL_PASSWORD=ixxxxxxxxx
MAIL_USE_TLS=?????
MAIL_USE_SSL=??????